# How to save binary data (with upper-byte values) into a unicode MySQL row

Tags: mysql, encoding, non-ascii-characters

I have a legacy system which is sending and reading binary data into an existing MySQL table (version 5.6.34 in case it matters).  I need to write to the same kind of data to the same kind of table in our new system (so parts of the old system can read it).  However, when I try to write binary data, MySQL seems to clip off anything in the upper-byte range (probably, whatever isn't valid unicode).

I cannot change the table. How do I write the same data.  (The old system is using a binary mysql driver in a different language, so I can't replicate whatever it's doing).

```
mysql> create table foobar (a_session longtext character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> insert into foobar values (_binary X'4D798053514C');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.12 sec)

mysql> select * from foobar;
+-----------+
| a_session |
+-----------+
| My        |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.13 sec)
```

I want some update/insert command that will instead display something like:

```
| My�SQL     |
```

and have the same binary bytes that I'm sending in the command.

Answer (score 0):

When running that little test, also provide

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
```

The `80` is not a very good 'character':

```
big5, binary, cp932, eucjpms, euckr, gb2312,
           gbk, sjis, ujis, utf8, utf8mb4   0  0 ''
                              ascii, swe7   1  1 '?'
armscii8, dec8, greek, hebrew, hp8, latin2,
                   latin5, latin7, tis620   2  1 ''
                                   cp1251   2  1 'Ђ'
                    cp850, cp852, keybcs2   2  1 'Ç'
                                    cp866   2  1 'А'
                          macce, macroman   2  1 'Ä'
  cp1250, cp1256, cp1257, geostd8, latin1   3  1 '€'
                             koi8r, koi8u   3  1 '─'
```

That is, `latin1` (and a few other `CHARACTER SETs`) interpret hex 80 as `Euro`; other charsets give you less interesting things.  What were you expecting??